# Change format of a specific word using CSS

Tags: css

Text can come form different source. After getting text it will display on site. From this text I need to change format of a specific word using CSS. In following example `database` word have to change:

[image]

It is easily done by JavaScript **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/42t159nw/)** but I need it by CSS not by JavaScript. Any idea?

Comment: No...CSS can't detect content. JS is your only option unless you wrap each instance of the word in a classed element like a span.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text

Answer (score 2):

You cannot select content with CSS, but with jQuery you can.
You could wrap "database" in span and then use CSS to style it.
For example:

HTML:

```
<p>A <span class="database">database</span> is a collection of information. In one view <span class="database">database</span> can be classified.</p>
```

CSS:

```
.database {color: red;}
```

When it comes to jQuery:

```
$( "p:contains('database')" ).css( "color", "red" );
```

That would probably be the easiest solution, but I personally don't like it.