# How to force a word to always be displayed in uppercase letters?

Tags: css, letter

I would like to automatically capitalize the work "like" everytime it's displayed on "facebook.com". How can I do it?

I'm using the Chrome extension "StyleBot" to edit my CSS.

Comment: CSS is content "unaware", meaning it can't read the text, so you would need JS or some other scripting language for this to work.

Comment: Hello there, Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question, so you will get a suitable answer. Read the docs on how to [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do that with CSS, unless the word "like" is in separate tag everytime. CSS cannot parse through the document text to find words. You'll need to use javascript for that.

Comment: There's already an answer to this question. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31811905/change-format-of-a-specific-word-using-css